# Watin - how I can do the testing on different versions of Internet Explorer?

Tags: watin

I need to do tests on different versions of Internet Explorer browser, but not WATIN.CORE.IE a method that would alter the version of browser used. I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need multiple [virtual machines](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575) each installed with a different version of ie because you cannot install ie versions side by side (There are a few hacks but you never get a true representation).

Comment: ok, but there are ways to simulate the action of choosing the mode of the browser version of Internet Explorer? or is there some way of knowing which is the version of the browser is run from the WatiN?

Answer (score 2):

You can query the registry to get the IE version.

To output the full version number to the NUnit console do the following.

```
        var ieKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer");
        if (ieKey == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IE key not found");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Version:" + (string)ieKey.GetValue("Version"));
        }
```

The above was verified using: Windows 7, IE8 and WatiN 2.0

Thanks be to Jeroen as the registry call is copied verbatim out of IE.cs